# Does $\text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i,\bigoplus_{j\in J}N_j)\cong\prod_{i\in I}\bigoplus_{j\in J}\text{Hom}_R(M_i,N_j)$ hold for any sets $I,J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is stated as a result in Weintraub's & Adkins' "Algebra" [image]
and the result is used at several junctions (e.g. when proving the uniqueness of a factorisation in simple modules).

[image]

The identity that is known to me is $\text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i,\prod_{j\in J}N_j)\cong\prod_{i\in I}\prod_{j\in J}\text{Hom}_R(M_i,N_j)$ and I can't find any valid proof of the above result. In fact, other questions on MSE seem to suggest that the identity does not hold for arbitrary sums, so I'm curious how the authors justify this result and its use.